# SQL server management studio - assign colour/formatting to aliases

Tags: sql-server-2008, colors, formatting, alias

I am currently using SQL server 2008, and I was wondering whether there was any way to format aliases within the server management studio window so that they stand out from other text (e.g. bold or coloured). We have a team of three who share a lot of queries, so any way to help us understand what the others have written would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Tools/Options/Enviroment/Fonts and Colors` there are lot of options to change. But I do not remember that ' aliases' are included as a single item. According to [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173443.aspx) there is no option to change only aliases. Maybe using an external tool? I use `SMSS Tools` and `Poor's Man formatter` to format my queries and neither of them can do it.

Comment: That's a shame. Ah well, thanks for the answer - You've saved me a lot of wasted fiddling time!

Comment: You are welcome... maybe somone else can recommend some tool that can have this option. I do not know if RedGate or Idera has some tool that allows this kind of accurrate colouring.

Answer (score 0):

I use RedGate SQLPrompt to automatically format my columns as 'ALIAS' = column_name.  If you put your alias in single quotes then it stands out because it is colored as a string.  Works great, except I understand this syntax has been deprecated in Azure.